# Create Expression in Report Builder 3.0 Report to sum a column

Tags: aggregate-functions, reportbuilder3.0

I created a report with 3 columns, Department, Ticket Count, Ticket Number. It groups Department names and the second column shows 1 instance of the Ticket Count.  The last column shows all of the ticket numbers.

I added a row that shows the grand total of all of the departments displayed.

This is the data set results :

```
Department   TicketCount TicketNumber
D1           3           12345
D1           3           22345
D1           3           32345
```

I group the Department and the TicketCount so that the display is like this:

```
 Department   TicketCount TicketNumber
    D1           3           12345
                             22345
                             32345
```

I want to add a ticket total at the end but the result is always adding all of the ticket counts and not just one.
So the Total displayed is 9 not 3.

I need to create an expression that picks the distinct TicketCounts of the departments and sums them.

The function DistinctCount returns the correct number of counts when I have multiple departments but not the values.

I tried the RunningValue function but it adds all of the values in the column.

```
=RunningValue(Fields!ReopenedTicketCount.Value, sum, Nothing)
```

I need to create a function that sums the distinct values of the ticket counts of each department.

Can anyone point me in the direction as to the functions that I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.  I just used the COUNT function on the third column to get the grand total.